# C# Winforms: selective disabling of UI whilst a thread runs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a quite complex form that presents an option to run a script (our own type). Whilst it runs, I don't want to lock the UI completely, so I would like to start it in a thread. So far so good, but to prevent the user messing with things I need to selectively disable parts of the UI. I could recursively set Enabled = false and then Enabled = true when the thread ends. But this ignores the state of the control at the time of running (ie controls which were disabled for various reasons would be incorrectly re-enabled). Short of building a tree of booleans, is there some other way to block input (such as the GlassPane type in Java)?

Comment: There is an Opactity property of the Form Control, depending on your design you can use one form to effectively mask another form by setting the Opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `DoEvents`, it's [evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html).

Use a panel and add all the controls you want to disable in it. When the panel will be disabled, all inner controls will appear to be disabled but the value of their `Enabled` property won't be actually modified.

Here's a working example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Disables UI elements using the panel
            this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(false);

            // Starts the background work
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(this.Worker));
        }

        private void Worker(object state)
        {
            // Simulates some work
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // Now the work is done, enable the panel
            this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(true);
        }

        private void SetPanelEnabledProperty(bool isEnabled)
        {
            // InvokeRequired is used to manage the case the UI is modified
            // from another thread that the UI thread
            if (this.panel1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.panel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(isEnabled)));
            }
            else
            {
                this.panel1.Enabled = isEnabled;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a panel populated with the controls you want disabling while the script runs, then re-enable the panel when the script has ended.

Alternatively you could start a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for the script.

Comment: +1 For using a containing panel -- setting the `Enabled` property of the panel to false will disable all contained controls, and setting it to true will restore their original state.  Much better than the recursive method the OP was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this either using the Application.DoEvents() method, or you have to write a delegate which invokes the corosponding control.
I think the Application.DoEvents() would be the simplest way.
You should call Application.DoEvents() in the loop on your thread.

For the delegate version, you find here some information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: Don't call Application.DoEvents from any other thread but the main UI thread.  You might not have meant to suggest it, but your answer is not quite clear on this matter.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() will help you. Use it inside timer which ticks very often